# Idea does not recognize plugins (on scala) for Play framework 2.1.1

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to configure a play framework 2.1.1 project to work in Idea with some plugins.

For instance I want to use Mailer plugin from here:
https://github.com/typesafehub/play-plugins/tree/master/mailer

My configuration:

Build.scala

```
object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

  val appName         = "testplay"
  val appVersion      = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

  val appDependencies = Seq(
    // Add your project dependencies here,
    javaCore,
    javaJdbc,
    javaEbean,
    "com.typesafe" % "play-plugins-mailer_2.10" % "2.1-SNAPSHOT"
  )

  val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
    // Add your own project settings here      
  )

}
```

plugins.sbt

```
// Comment to get more information during initialization
logLevel := Level.Warn

// The Typesafe repository
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.1.1")
```

build.properties

```
sbt.version=0.12.2
```

app is generated by play idea and I've just added Mailer dependency.

Code which uses plugin to send email is not recognized by idea as valid.
Is there a way to fix this? May be I need to add some dependencies manually?

Code is working on server, but it is quite annoying as I cannot validate code in IDE without deploying it.

Thanks for responses.

Comment: Looks like formalizing the question itself helps to find answer much quicker.
I have resolved this just downloaded the plugin itself from: http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/maven-snapshots/com/typesafe/play-plugins-mailer_2.10/2.1-SNAPSHOT/play-plugins-mailer_2.10-2.1-SNAPSHOT.jar and added it to project dependencies in idea. Question can be closed, but hopefully it will help anybody else to resolve dependencies problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to relaunch the `idea` command, after sbt has refreshed your dependencies

- Add a dependency in Build.Scala
- sbt> `reload`
- sbt> `idea`

Open idea, a popup will alert you to reload the project.